# In wallpaper app i am getting Gap beside the image in fullScreenView

Tags: javascript, android, android-wallpaper

Plz Look at the below image i am getting Gap beside the image in full screen view anyone plz help
Please have a look on my code and tell me what's wrong with it.

If there is any solution plz explain me clearly step-by-step (I am New to android)

[Gap Beside Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5IPR.jpg)

package com.saveitornot.wallit;

**FullscreenViewActivity.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.app.AppController;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.picasa.model.Wallpaper;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.utils.Utils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = FullScreenViewActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_IMAGE = "selectedImage";
    private Wallpaper selectedPhoto;
    private ImageView fullImageView;
    private LinearLayout llSetWallpaper, llDownloadWallpaper;
    private Utils utils;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();



    private String licencseURL,licenseeURL = null;

    // Picasa JSON response node keys
    private static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP = "media$group",
            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT = "media$content", TAG_IMG_URL = "url",
            TAG_IMG_WIDTH = "width", TAG_IMG_HEIGHT = "height";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

        fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
        llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
        llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);
        pbLoader.setIndeterminate(true);
        pbLoader.setMax(100);



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
                .coordinatorLayout);


        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        // layout click listeners
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);

        // setting layout buttons alpha/opacity
        llSetWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        llDownloadWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        selectedPhoto = (Wallpaper) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);

        // check for selected photo null
        if (selectedPhoto != null) {

            // fetch photo full resolution image by making another json request
            fetchFullResolutionImage();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Fetching image fullresolution json
     * */


    private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
        String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

        // show loader before making request
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llSetWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        // volley's json obj request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Image full resolution json: "
                                + response.toString());
                try {
                    // Parsing the json response
                    JSONObject entry = response
                            .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                    JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                    JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                            .get(0);

                    String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                            .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                    // image full resolution widht and height
                    final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                    final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                            + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                            + ", h: " + height);

                    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                            .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                    // We download image into ImageView instead of
                    // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                    // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                    // methods

                    ///
                    progressStatus = 0;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (progressStatus<100){
                                progressStatus += 1;
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        pbLoader.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                    }
                                });
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                }catch (InterruptedException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                    ///

                    imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                            new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(
                                        VolleyError arg0) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(
                                        ImageLoader.ImageContainer response,
                                        boolean arg1) {
                                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                        // load bitmap into imageview

                                        fullImageView
                                                .setImageBitmap(response
                                                        .getBitmap());
                                        adjustImageAspect(width, height);


                                        // hide loader and show set &
                                        // download buttons
                                        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        llSetWallpaper
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        llDownloadWallpaper
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        getSupportActionBar().show();

                                    }
                                }
                            });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                // unable to fetch wallpapers
                // either google username is wrong or
                // devices doesn't have internet connection
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        // Remove the url from cache
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

        // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    /**
     * Adjusting the image aspect ration to scroll horizontally, Image height
     * will be screen height, width will be calculated respected to height
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int sHeight = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            sHeight = display.getHeight();
        }

        int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
                / (double) bHeight);
        params.width = new_width;
        params.height = sHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen image new dimensions: w = " + new_width
                + ", h = " + sHeight);

        fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    /**
     * View click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            // button Download Wallpaper tapped
            case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
                utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                break;
            // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
            case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
                utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fullscreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void gotoURL(String url)
    {
        Uri uri =  Uri.parse(url);
        Intent goToWebsite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
        // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
        int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            flags |= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT;
        }
        else
        {
            //noinspection deprecation
            flags |= Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET;
        }
        goToWebsite.addFlags(flags);

        try {
            startActivity(goToWebsite);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_set_as_wallpaper:
                utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_download:
                utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_share:
                utils.shareImage(bitmap, coordinatorLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_report:
                utils.reportImage(bitmap);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

}
```

**ManiActivity.java**

```
package com.saveitornot.wallit;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.saveitornot.wallit.app.AppController;
import com.saveitornot.wallit.picasa.model.Category;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    private List<Category> albumsList;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;


    String name = new String("Main Grid Screen");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // Getting the albums from shared preferences
        albumsList = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger().getCategories();

        // Insert "Recently Added" in navigation drawer first position
       /* Category recentAlbum = new Category(null, getString(R.string.nav_drawer_recently_added), "(100)");

        albumsList.add(0, recentAlbum);*/

        // Loop through albums in add them to navigation drawer adapter
        for (Category a : albumsList) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(true, a.getId(), a.getTitle(), a.getPhotoNo()));
            // titles a.getTitle()
        }
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        displayView(0);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String albumId = "";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Recently added item selected
                // don't pass album id to grid fragment
                /*Log.e(TAG, "GridFragment is creating");
                fragment = GridFragment.newInstance(null);*/
                 albumId = albumsList.get(position).getId();
                fragment = GridFragment.newInstance(albumId);
                break;

            default:
                // selected wallpaper category
                // send album id to grid fragment to list all the wallpapers
                albumId = albumsList.get(position).getId();
                fragment = GridFragment.newInstance(albumId);
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(albumsList.get(position).getTitle());
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

}
```

Here is an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FullScreenViewActivity">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbLoader"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:progress="1">
        </ProgressBar>


        <!-- Scroll view for fullscreen preview -->

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <!-- Set as wallpaper button -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSetWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_apply" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/set_wallpaper"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Download wallpaper button -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDownloadWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_download" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/download_wallpaper"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/fragmentToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            />





    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can u post the XML

Answer (score 0):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="1">
```

try change the android:layout_width="wrap_content" to  android:layout_width="match_parent". Does it help?

Comment: Use scrollView instead of HorizontalScrollView, i have tried at my side, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbLoader"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:progress="1">
        </ProgressBar>


        <!-- Scroll view for fullscreen preview -->

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_onboarding_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <!-- Set as wallpaper button -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSetWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_cashback"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fas_void" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="wallpaper"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Download wallpaper button -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDownloadWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_cashback_ds"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_flag_default" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="1234"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/fragmentToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            />





    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

That is how i modify your layout. I can see the image fill up the screen.

Comment: I did te same. but no change